# Kotlin fallback wrapper

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm looking for an elegant solution to the following.

I'd like to implement a `Wrapper` class that:

- Accepts 2 implementations of the same `Interface`, and returns a new instance of that same `Interface`.
- Any method call to the Wrapper object, tries to call the same method on the 1st implementation.
- If the first call results into `UnsupportedOperationException`, then the 2th implementation should be used instead.

```
interface API {
    fun getData(): String
}

class Main: API {
    override fun getData(): String {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }
}

class Fallback: API {
    override fun getData(): String {
        return "data"
    }
}

class Wrapper {
    companion object {
        fun getInstance(main: API, fallback: API): API {
            // TODO
        }
    }
}

class Test {
    @Test
    fun `invokes the fallback instance`() {
        val wrapper = Wrapper.getInstance(Main(), Fallback())
        val response = wrapper.getData()
        assertEquals(response, "data")
    }
}
```

The best thing I have come up with so far is Delegate with Overrides:

```
class Wrapper(fallback: API): API by Main() {
    val fallback = fallback
    override fun getData(): String {
        return fallback.getData()
    }
}
```

What I don't like about this solution is that:

- It requires overriding each unsupported operation
- It gets quite verbose as the Interface grows into a complex multilevel structure with more sub interfaces

I'd also like to avoid Reflection for performance reasons and because this is a Kotlin Multiplatform project.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,
Juan

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed solution won't work because it will always favor the fallback for any overridden function.

There's no solution for your needs that can avoid having to manually handle every function of your interface. But you can have an intermediate function that handles the cascading selection of implementation for functions with the same signature.

```
class Wrapper (private val delegates: Array<out API>): API {

    companion object {
        fun getInstance(vararg delegates: API) = Wrapper(delegates)
    }

    private fun <R> delegate0Arg(function: API.() -> R): R {
        for (delegate in delegates) {
            try {
                return delegate.function()
            } catch (e: UnsupportedOperationException) {
                // continue
            }
        }
        throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }

    override val name: String get() = delegate0Arg(API::name)
    override fun getData(): String = delegate0Arg(API::getData)

}
```

But you would need additional functions to handle each unique number of arguments the interface functions have.

```
private fun <T, R> delegate1Arg(t: T, function: API.(t: T) -> R): R {
    for (delegate in delegates) {
        try {
            return delegate.function(t)
        } catch (e: UnsupportedOperationException) {
            // continue
        }
    }
    throw UnsupportedOperationException()
}

override fun getData(x: String) = delegate1Arg(x, API::getData)
```

Comment: That's something. Thank you :)